# Converting a C++ implementation of Error Level Analysis to C#

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to implement [Error Level Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_level_analysis) in C#. I have found examples in C++ using OpenCV and Python using PIL, but cannot find any in C#, so I am trying to convert C++ code using the OpenCvSharp library.

Here is the example I have used:

```
// Control
int scale = 15,
quality = 75;

// Image containers
cv::Mat input_image,
compressed_image;

void processImage(int, void*)
{
    // Setting up parameters and JPEG compression
    std::vector<int> parameters;
    parameters.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY);
    parameters.push_back(quality);
    cv::imwrite("temp.jpg", input_image, parameters);

    // Reading temp image from the disk
    compressed_image = cv::imread("temp.jpg");
 
    if (compressed_image.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "> Error loading temp image" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    cv::Mat output_image = cv::Mat::zeros(input_image.size(), CV_8UC3);

    // Compare values through matrices
    for (int row = 0; row < input_image.rows; ++row)
    {
        const uchar* ptr_input = input_image.ptr<uchar>(row);
        const uchar* ptr_compressed = compressed_image.ptr<uchar>(row);
        uchar* ptr_out = output_image.ptr<uchar>(row);
   
        for (int column = 0; column < input_image.cols; column++)
        {
            // Calc abs diff for each color channel multiplying by a scale factor
            ptr_out[0] = abs(ptr_input[0] - ptr_compressed[0]) * scale;
            ptr_out[1] = abs(ptr_input[1] - ptr_compressed[1]) * scale;
            ptr_out[2] = abs(ptr_input[2] - ptr_compressed[2]) * scale;

            ptr_input += 3;
            ptr_compressed += 3;
            ptr_out += 3;
        }
    }

    // Shows processed image
    cv::imshow("Error Level Analysis", output_image);
}
```

Here is my attempt so far:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Control
    int scale = 15;
    int quality = 75;

    string test_img_path = "";
    // Image container
    OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    fdlg.Title = "C# Corner Open File Dialog";
    fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\Documents\Pictures";
    fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    fdlg.FilterIndex = 2;
    fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
    if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        test_img_path = fdlg.FileName;
    }

    Mat input_image = Cv2.ImRead(test_img_path);
    Mat compressed_image;
    // Setting up parameters and JPEG compression

    int[] Params = new int[2];
    Params.Append(95);
    Params.Append(50);
    Cv2.ImWrite("temp.jpg", input_image, Params);

    // Reading temp image from the disk
    compressed_image = Cv2.ImRead("temp.jpg");

    if (compressed_image.Empty())
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("File empty");
    }

    Mat output_image = Mat.Zeros(input_image.Size(), MatType.CV_8UC3);

    // Compare values through matrices
    for (int row = 0; row < input_image.Rows; ++row)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            char* ptr_input = (char*)input_image.Ptr(row);
            char* ptr_compressed = (char*)compressed_image.Ptr(row);
            char* ptr_out = (char*)output_image.Ptr(row);

            for (int column = 0; column < input_image.Cols; column++)
            {
                // Calc abs diff for each color channel multiplying by a scale factor
                ptr_out[0] = (char)((ptr_input[0] - ptr_compressed[0]) * scale);
                ptr_out[1] = (char)(Math.Abs(ptr_input[1] - ptr_compressed[1]) * scale);
                ptr_out[2] = (char)(Math.Abs(ptr_input[2] - ptr_compressed[2]) * scale);

                ptr_input += 3;
                ptr_compressed += 3;
                ptr_out += 3;
            }
        }
    }

    // Shows processed image
    Cv2.ImShow("Error Level Analysis", output_image);
}
```

The above will not compile, and leads to the error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Any help in conversion, or a methodology to do ELA using C#, would be appreciated.

Comment: You have stated everything BUT the problem. What's wrong? Is this working? Are you not getting the results you expect?

Comment: I have edited it to state the problem - it's not working at all, and I'm unsure what it is that's going wrong. The OpenCvSharp documentation is pretty thin, and trying to convert over the syntax directly just doesn't seem to work - I wish I could be more exact, but I'm honestly not even sure what it is that isn't working.

Comment: You mentioned that: *".The above code will not compile..."*. Could you please put the compilation error so we can help you without needing to reproduce the code elsewhere?

Comment: @SebastianInones I have updated the code and the provided the error that I get, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the name of opencv lib you are using? OpenCvSharp?

Comment: @Hihikomori Yes, I'm using OpenCvSharp, but I'm happy to use any library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) instead, which you can install from [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation). Then you can transform the code to C# like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;

class Program
{
    // Control
    readonly int scale = 15, quality = 75;

    // Image containers
    Mat input_image, compressed_image;

    void ProcessImage()
    {
        // Setting up parameters and JPEG compression
        KeyValuePair<ImwriteFlags, int> parameters = new KeyValuePair<ImwriteFlags, int>(ImwriteFlags.JpegQuality, quality);
        CvInvoke.Imwrite("temp.jpg", input_image, parameters);

        // Reading temp image from the disk
        compressed_image = CvInvoke.Imread("temp.jpg");

        if (compressed_image.IsEmpty)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("> Error loading temp image");
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        Mat output_image = Mat.Zeros(input_image.Rows, input_image.Cols, DepthType.Cv8U, 3);

        byte[] input, compressed, output;
        input = new byte[input_image.Rows* input_image.Cols* 3];
        compressed = new byte[input_image.Rows * input_image.Cols * 3];
        output = new byte[input_image.Rows * input_image.Cols * 3];
        input_image.CopyTo(input);
        compressed_image.CopyTo(compressed);

        // Compare values through matrices
        for (int row = 0; row < input_image.Rows; ++row)
            for (int column = 0; column < input_image.Cols; column++)
                for (int channel = 0; channel < 3; channel++)
                    // Calc abs diff for each color channel multiplying by a scale factor
                    output[(row * input_image.Cols + column) * 3 + channel] = (byte)(Math.Abs(input[(row * input_image.Cols + column) * 3 + channel] - compressed[(row * input_image.Cols + column) * 3 + channel]) * scale);

        byte[] t = new byte[1];  
        for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
        {
            t[0] = output[i];
            Marshal.Copy(t, 0, output_image.DataPointer + i, 1);
        }

        // Shows processed image
        CvInvoke.Imshow("Error Level Analysis", output_image); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I am getting the error :
```System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in regards to the 'Mat Input Image'```

Whilst if I set it the line to: 
```Mat Input Image = CvInvoke.Imread(Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ela_frog.jpg"), Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.AnyColor);```

Then an image does show, but it's of lots of grey blurred lines instead of ELA.

Comment: @Retro Try it now. I made a mistake in converting the array into `Mat`, but now it works, and I compared it with C++ results.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is perfect. 
For future readers, I created the input_image Mat with: `Mat input_image = CvInvoke.Imread(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "ela_test_1.jpg"), ImreadModes.AnyColor);`

Answer (score 0):

// Control
int scale = 15;
int quality = 75;

```
        // Image containers
        Mat input_image = new Mat();
        Mat compressed_image;
        // Setting up parameters and JPEG compression


        int[] Params = new int[2];
        Params.Append(95);
        Params.Append(50);
        Cv2.ImWrite("temp.jpg", input_image, Params);

        // Reading temp image from the disk
        compressed_image = Cv2.ImRead("temp.jpg");

        if (compressed_image.Empty())
        {
            Trace.WriteLine("File empty");
        }

        Mat output_image = Mat.Zeros(input_image.Size(), MatType.CV_8UC3);

        // Compare values through matrices
        for (int row = 0; row < input_image.Rows; ++row)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                char* ptr_input = (char*)input_image.Ptr(row);
                char* ptr_compressed = (char*)compressed_image.Ptr(row);
                char* ptr_out = (char*)output_image.Ptr(row);

                for (int column = 0; column < input_image.Cols; column++)
                {
                    // Calc abs diff for each color channel multiplying by a scale factor
                    ptr_out[0] = (char)((ptr_input[0] - ptr_compressed[0]) * scale);
                    ptr_out[1] = (char)(Math.Abs(ptr_input[1] - ptr_compressed[1]) * scale);
                    ptr_out[2] = (char)(Math.Abs(ptr_input[2] - ptr_compressed[2]) * scale);

                    ptr_input += 3;
                    ptr_compressed += 3;
                    ptr_out += 3;
                }
            }

        }

        // Shows processed image
        Cv2.ImShow("Error Level Analysis", output_image);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help, I am getting the following error on ptr_out[0]....:
System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

Answer (score 0):

An access to pixels values can be done by the following code. You can not access protected memory by pointer.

```
using Mat mat = new Mat(FilePath.Image.Lenna, ImreadModes.Color);
            for (int y = 0; y < mat.Height; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < mat.Width; x++)
                {
                    Vec3b color = mat.Get<Vec3b>(y, x);
                    Vec3b newColor = new Vec3b(color.Item2, color.Item1, color.Item0);
                    mat.Set<Vec3b>(y, x, newColor);
                }
            }
```

There are a lot of examples how to use opencv in c#. Check [here](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp_samples/tree/7db6cc437d17e214812ba948740e8d8e4aa86792/SamplesCS/Samples).